# how to check mysql query execution time in whole code

Tags: php, mysql

I am looking for the solution to check mysql execution time of query after code runs.

Is there any way to achieve this ? I have done in PHPMYADMIN , its showing whole log, but how it will be achieved when i am working with project ?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/performance-schema-query-profiling.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code to get a execution time of sql query

```
$sql = '...';
$msc = microtime(true);
mysql_query($sql);
$msc = microtime(true)-$msc;
echo $msc . ' s'; // in seconds
echo ($msc * 1000) . ' ms'; // in millseconds
```

Hope this one worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
  EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM table_name
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-tutorial-visual-explain-dbt3.html

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check execution time in your project than you can use [`microtime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php) for calculation of `start` and `end` time as:

**Example of MYSQLi:**

```
<?
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "yourUser", "yourPassword", "YourDB");
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM yourQuery";
$start = microtime(true);
mysqli_query($link,$SQL);
$end = microtime(true) - $start;
echo $end; // result in seconds
?>
```